# Change JFrame size dynamically to JTable contents

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

I've got myself stuck again.

This time I have a `JTable` inside a `JFrame`.

I basically just want there to be no "white-space" below the table generated.

When resizing, the rows don't change height, but the columns change width for some reason. Is it at all possible to not have the white space below?

[image]
I'd prefer not to have a scrollbar if it at all possible, and just show the entire table with the white space removed, so even when resized, it doesn't show up.

**Quick Update: i used the gridlayout layout and it kind of worked, but my header has a bigger font than the table, resulting in the cells to be shown properly, but the headers being cutoff and displayed as "Hea..."**

[image]

Comment: Have you ever seen an application that resizes *itself*? I really think you are approaching this from the wrong angle. Toplevel windows dont just change their size. Instead: use JScrollpanes, and keep the frame size fixed (or maybe manually resizable).

Comment: *able to show the contents of each row/column*  - how do you know that is practical? What if the table has a 1000 rows or 100 columns? The table should be designed to be a specific reasonable size and then you allow scroll bars to appear when necessary. *without any of the "..."* - Check out: [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) which can dynamically resize the column widths depending on the data in the table model.

Comment: Well its my database and i know nothing is more than like 5 rows, its really just a learning/practicality to not have to set a fixed size for each jframe, but have it figured out by the frame itself @camickr

Comment: Its not about resizing itself, its about setting the size before its shown @GhostCat

Comment: Well, knowing how to use scroll panes is still the more valuable concept ... the problem with setting fixed sizes is: you have to know them. You spent a lot of time getting that information.

Comment: *but have it figured out by the frame itself* - you add components to the frame and pack() the frame before making the frame visible. This is standard for any frame, no matter what  components you add to the frame. You should not be attempting to use the setSize() method.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it at all possible to not have the whitespace below?

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
frame.add(scrollPane);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

Comment: iirc this adds a scroll thingy when the table gets too small to display everything right? is it possible to set the minimum/maximum size to show everything inside the table without having to resize/set a size/having to scroll?

Comment: Setting the preferred scrollable viewport size of the table to the preferred size of the table, will omit the scrollbars from the scroll pane @Leno22ß6. So you should be good with this answer.

Comment: @TT. do you know if i have to use gridlayout to use pack(); efficiently? because in my setup using pack makes the windows 0px and only shows the bar on top very small, it doesnt automatically set the size to the prefered size to display every cell properly.

Comment: BTW @camickr this solution did work to some extend and i appreciate the answer

Comment: quick update, i used the gridlayout layout and it kind of worked, but my header has a bigger font than the table, resulting in the cells to be shown properly, but the headers being cutoff and displayed as "Hea..."

Comment: @Leno22ß6 *this solution did work to some extend * - this solution WILL solve all your problems. I have no idea why you are asking about a GridLayout. It literally takes the above 6 statement to test the solution. The only change you need to make is: `JTable table = news JTable( new DefaultTableModel(5, 5) )`. Now you will actually have a table with 5 rows and columns . And of course you need to create the frame before you add the table to it.

Comment: Regarding the header size. You were given a suggestion for this problem in my original comment to the question. Did you even follow the link provided? Must admit I haven't tested the suggestion when the font of the header is different than the font of the table, so I'll leave that up to you to verify. So yes, you have a complete solution to your problem. However you keep updating your question changing the problem so how do you expect us to provide a consistent solution. The question should be asked properly the first time so there is no need to update it.

Comment: *iirc this adds a scroll thingy when the table gets too small* - try the suggestion BEFORE commenting. If I can spend the time helping and posting code, the least you can do is test the suggestion before assuming it won't work. The answer should have been "accepted" long ago. If you have multiple problems then you ask a different question.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer (by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.